# How to move cursor to my first todo entry

Tags: org-mode

Is there any way to move the cursor (point) to the first todo entry in my org file?
Is there any built-in function in org-mode? if no, any elisp code that can do that is welcome.

I had tried this function:

```
org-show-todo-tree
```

This will only search(and unfold) for todo entries without pointing to the first todo item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
(defun org-goto-first-todo ()
  "Jump to the first TODO entry in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (outline-next-heading)
  (while (not (org-entry-is-todo-p))
    (forward-line 1)))
```

Comment: Thnak you, this works for me.
So there is no a built-in org-mode function?

Comment: Can you wrap your solution in an interactive command that can be bound to a key for clarity?